# What is the differenc between 'attribute' and 'in' using glsl?

Tags: opengl, glsl

What is the difference between writing

```
in vec3 position;
```

or

```
attribute vec3 position;
```

in a glsl shader?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`attribute` and `varying` are deprecated since glsl 1.3 and were removed in glsl 1.4:

Here the extract from  the [glsl 1.4 specs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.40.08.pdf) (*1.2.6 Summary of Functionality differences from version 1.2*):

> The following is a summary of features deprecated in version 1.3:
>
> - Use of the keywords *attribute* and *varying* (use *in* and *out*).

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  OpenGL ES uses them, and it's newer.

Comment: @Jessy first of all, _OpenGL_ and _OpenGL ES_ don't adapt all changes at the same time, so you can not really say one is newer then the other. But if you look at the [GLSL ES 3.00 specs](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.4.pdf) you will see: [...] Not all language constructs present in _v1.00_ of the language are available in _v3.00_ e.g. **attribute** 
and **varying** qualifiers. [...]

Comment: This is weird, because when using opengl es headers through Android's GLES32, using in results in the shader compiler logging an error saying "ERROR: 0:1: 'shader in & out declarations' : requires language version 300"